# Best practice when echo repeated code

Tags: php, html

I have a question that bothers me for a long time. Lets say i have a code with several nested div's and span's. All these compose a square with an image inside.

```
echo '<div> <div> <div> <div> <span> <img src='.$image.'> </span></div></div></div>';
```

Only that this code has about 15 rows.

From what i know when echo-ing the results from db in that form i put in the loop the whole html code. It looks clumsy this way.

It is there a better practice ?

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $row->address_link=strtolower($row->network);
    echo '<li class="col-md-3 isotope-item '.$row->network.'">';    
                                echo '<div class="portfolio-item img-thumbnail">';
                               echo '<table border="0"><tr>';
                                    echo '<a href="order/'.$row->address_link.'/'.$row->value.'" class="thumb-info">';                                     
                                       echo '<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="img/'.$row->address_link.'.png">';
                                        echo '<span class="thumb-info-title">';
                                            echo '<span class="thumb-info-inner">'.$row->value.' Euro</span>';                                            
                                        echo '</span>';
                                        echo '<span class="thumb-info-action">';
                                            echo '<span title="Universal" href="order/'.$row->address_link.'/'.$row->value.'" class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="icon icon-link"></i></span>';     
                                        echo '</span>'; 
                                    echo '</a>';
                                echo '</div>';
                                 echo '</tr><tr>';
                            echo '<span class="thumb-info-type">'.$row->value*$row->rate.' Eur</span>';
                            echo '</tr></table>';
                            echo '</li>';    
}
```

Comment: why do u need to view source code?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "when echo-ing the results from db in that form i put in the loop the whole html code"? x

Comment: I don't know what your "square with an image inside" actually looks like, but it's highly unlikely that you really need five layers nested markup like this; most of those `<div>` tags are probably unnecessary.

Comment: This is how my code looks like and it's clumsy. I wonder if it's any way to make it cleaner(except function). If i echo one string insead of all this code will be faster? The script will have to render from db about 300 products so on 10 users simultaneously will be very much for the server.

Comment: that 4 wrapped `div`s doesn't look right. learn CSS.

Comment: I am using a theme, i don't like CSS i'm sorry, i like better PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to php you can define a `function` for this:

```
function wrapImage($src){
   return '<div> <div> <div> <div> <span> <img src='.$src.'> </span></div></div></div>';
}
```

And just use  `echo wrapImage($src)` where you need it with different params.

EDIT: consider following way of presenting the data:

```
<?php 
    $query = 'select * from Unicorns';
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $row->address_link=strtolower($row->network);
?>   
    <!-- html -->
    <li class="col-md-3 isotope-item <?php echo $row->network; ?>">  
        <div class="portfolio-item img-thumbnail">
            <table border="0"><tr>
                <a href="order/<?php echo $row->address_link.'/'.$row->value; ?>" class="thumb-info">                                   
                    <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="img/'.$row->address_link.'.png">
                        <span class="thumb-info-title">
                        <span class="thumb-info-inner"><?php echo $row->value; ?> Euro</span>                                            
                    </span>
                    <span class="thumb-info-action">
                        <span title="Universal" href="order/<?php echo $row->address_link.'/'.$row->value ?>" class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="icon icon-link"></i></span>  
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            </tr><tr>
        <span class="thumb-info-type"><?php echo ($row->value*$row->rate); ?> Eur</span>
        </tr></table>
        </li>
     <!-- /html -->
<?php } ?>
```

It is called [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) .. and it is NOT the best practice but is better then your example in case the HTML is more then the PHP data.

Comment: I believe this is the best way also including it in a function to structure the code.

Comment: if your file is too big, you can try to move the html "template" in another file and load it with the preset data.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, dont use echo in loops (optimalization), store your output in variable and print it only once.

Repeated code can be stored inside function

```
function square($image){
  return '<div> <div> <div> <div> <span> <img src='.$image.'> </span></div></div></div>';
}
$output = '';
while ($loop){
  $output .= square($image);
}
echo $output
```

Comment: Ok so this is the best way i should go to optimize my output there, correct?

Comment: Well, this should be the best way to standarize your code "making it clean". If optimalization is your only goal, dont use function, if that loop is the only place those html divs are used.